# Set Default Maximum Rows for Export

Tags: security, export, vertica

I am more of a Vertica database user than admin, so I'm not even sure if what I'm asking is absurd, but here goes nothing...

1. **Could I, as an admin, put default restrictions on the number of rows that can be exported per export query?** I would like to make sure most users can only export a certain number of rows at a time, and that they cannot change the setting which prevents a massive export. I realize there are probably be ways around this restriction
2. **Would there also be a way to catch a user pulling small amounts of data incrementally from the same data set?**

An answer to question (1) would suffice, but I would appreciate any input on question (2), as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create views using `LIMIT` and give those view names to the end users. If you're using a development tool such as DBVisualizer, you can set the number of records to limit.

As always, [query labels](http://vertica.tips/2014/01/04/using-query-labels/) allow for easy tracking of any requests.

Comment: I think the views option would not work in my particular situation.

The labels idea is intriguing, but I'm not sure that would work. A few questions on that matter. What I would want, if some way to catch ANY attempt at an export query. So, if I could continuously check what appears to be called QUERY_PROFILES, and trigger a script that checks for the presence of a sufficient LIMIT clause as a determination for whether or not to manually kill the query.

Comment: Upon further reading, it seems like a trigger might be the key with other databases, but is not an option with Vertica.

Comment: Your use case doesn't make much sense to me. Vertica will still have to do the same processing to run the query. Your `LIMIT` will come at the end.

Comment: Is this an audit/compliance issue?

Comment: It's a legal compliance issue. We can't allow people to take out more than certain number of rows at a time. In theory, there are many ways around this... like pulling out all the records in a table slowly, over time etc. However, just to be on the safe side, we have to cover the more obvious attempts to take excessive amounts of personal information from the database.

Comment: The checking for a `LIMIT` before allowing the query to run idea was one such option. However, I think we'd need to cover other obvious pulls, like `vsql -o wholeFile.txt "select * from schema.table"`

Comment: Also, the reason I ask this question, is not because I'm in charge of making this decision at all. There is a setup that attempts to account for this as of now, which I won't go into, but it is a huge pain for all users and the admin. I am attempting to find other options to suggest.

Comment: @Audrey In the implementations I've seen, compliance was usually fine with being able to audit the requests table. An audit could have just been checking if there was any query run without a `LIMIT`, for example.